# quickly inspect OCR text layer on PDF file

Tags: pdf, ocr

Is there any program that will allow me to superimpose the text (OCR) layer of a PDF on top of the PDF rendering?

I want to quickly see if the text layer has errors or not.

It would be more convenient if that can be done with a program, if not, some cli command or script would also work.

Comment: In which programming language do you want to implement that program? And how did your OCR program add the text? (Drawing in rendering mode "invisible"? Drawing text regularly underneath?...)

Comment: Python would be ok. I used ocrmypdf to add the text.

Comment: unfortunately I can only help with java or c# pdf libraries. Nonetheless, not everyone knows "ocrmypdf", so that hint does not really answer how that program adds the text. If you don't know yourself, share a sample with ocr'ed text.

Comment: Java or C# is also ok. I mean that the OCR data is "sandwiched" in the document.

Comment: Here's an example pdf with ocr layer: http://docdro.id/G97YGFO

Comment: Hhmmm, according to your example file the text is drawn using a font called "GlyphLessFont". This font has an empty glyph for each character in it. Thus, there is no use "superimposing" this text on top: Even drawn above the image, this text looks empty! One could try and draw the letters at the positions using a different font if that's ok for you.

Comment: I don't really care about the way, I just need something that allows for quick inspection.

Answer (score 0):

Superimpose?  It implies you'd like to add text while I believe you'd like to have access to the text for detection and possibly further analysis of the OCRed text quality.  Perhaps need further clarification.

Our developers worked for some time on algorithms to detect the presence of text in PDFs and then evaluate its quality.  There are many cases that can trick a basic algorithm - Bates number or imprinter added into image-only PDF makes it seem like PDF has high-quality text while it has no actual text.  Some copiers produce "searchable PDFs" while using very low-quality OCR that contains many errors, but not necessarily on the first page that is typically some kind of title page with large fonts, thus the first line of the text encountered by an algorithm seems high quality.  Or the first page may have text while other pages do not, yet algorithm may believe the whole PDF has text.

In our commercial high-volume server-based OCR software (used by service bureaus, SaaS platforms,  libraries, backlog conversions, etc.) we now have advanced detection of PDFs with existing text layer and "smart decisions" which can filter out many of these false positive situations.  Our OCR can skip re-OCRing PDFs with high-quality text in PDFs.  If you are looking for a high-quality inexpensive OCR platform, such detection is a feature in it, but it can't be used separately without our OCR.  OCR workflow is used as a part of that filter.  Our developers wrote and integrated these algorithms without external tools.

I am with [www.wisetrend.com](http://www.wisetrend.com) where we provide software solutions and consulting for various OCR projects.

Comment: No, that's not what I want. I want to "draw" the recognized text on top of the pdf.

Comment: Draw recognized text?  Again unclear to me.  Are you asking how to add a text layer to an image PDF resulting in "Text over Image" (you see vector text) or "Text under Image" (you see the image but text exists under image coordinates) type of PDF?  In any case any PDF SDK can add or edit the text layer: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/928424